# Kmeans with an huge array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, k-means

I'm trying to find 5000 center points of a huge data set. My input array is [5000000][512] meaning a lot of vectors with 512 dimension. C++ has a limit on array size and I can't seems to overcome this. I wanted to use opencv kmeans function.
Any idea???

Comment: The limit would be memory not c++ vectors

Comment: Your input array meaning a lot of vectors? what?

Comment: Would this even compile?

Comment: Let's assume that's an array of (8-byte) doubles. If so, your array would occupy 19 gigabytes of memory. At the very least, you need a 64-bit chain (OS, compiler, etc.) and a rather a large amount of RAM for this.

Comment: It would not compile. Each row in the matrix is an input vector with 512 elements. I don't know how to break the data or how to do kmeans with more then one input matrix

Comment: You're asking to reserve a minimum of like 2.4 GB to as much as 19 GB as Jerry suggested... you're going to have to come up w/ a more clever way to handle this information.

Comment: If your input array data has continuous variations, you could consider using a multi-resolution approach. Say first you calculate K-means with sub-sampling of a factor of 16. That would reduce the data size from 5000000 to 312500. Then subsequentally expand into each region...

Comment: You need some online clustering algorithm or use something like Mahout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using mini batch kmeans which samples the data to batches. plus, the matrix was very sparse soo adding sparse matrix representation did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with guys above. The real question is that do you really have such a laptop/desktop with such huge memory. If the answer is Yes, you can simply write C programs to do the work. Otherwise, you may have to figure out a distributed solution, such as Mahout on Hadoop. Another option is that you may want to take sample out of all data somehow, and do clustering on the sample, if it is acceptable to your requirement.